# How to approximate a solution to a matrix equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, approximation-theory, approximation-algorithms

Suppose a matrix equation $Ax = b$ has no solution ($b$ is not in the column space of $A$)

How can I find a vector $x^\prime$ so that $Ax^\prime$ is the closest possible vector to $b$?

Comment: This is studied in every basic linear algebra course.

Comment: I so wish I hadn't made the half-hearted attempt to populate the site with questions in its first week of existence, before the level of appropriate questions had been established. Just delete it. And https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72/whats-an-example-of-a-function-whose-taylor-series-converges-to-the-wrong-thing and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81/when-does-a-matrix-equation-have-a-solution -- or migrate them to math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: But give me credit for asking three of the first 100 questions, at least. That's got to be worth something.

Comment: @MarkSapir But I am serious -- if you or anyone else can delete or migrate this, please do.

Comment: I did not notice that the question was posted in 2009. I cannot delete a question. I believe you can do that yourself if you want.

Comment: @MarkSapir No, not with an upvoted answer. /shrug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I want to correct something in both Anton's ans las3rjock's answers.  I hope that I am merely correcting bad notation.

The way to find x' (using the notation in the question) is, as correctly stated in each of the answers above, to derive the associated problem A<sup>T</sup> Ax' = A<sup>T</sup> b and solve that via Gaussian Elimination (also called Gauss-Jordan Elimination, the difference is technical and not important here).  This is **guaranteed** to have a solution.

The fact that this is the correct solution to the problem relies on the properties of the "closest point" of a point to a subspace.  We want the closest point to b on the subspace Im A.  Call this b'.  The properties of the "closest point" imply that the *difference*, b - b', is orthogonal to everything in Im A.  It's simple to draw a picture to convince yourself that if c is in Im A and b - c is *not* orthogonal to everything in Im A then it is possible to "nudge" c a little, either away or towards the origin, to c' so that b - c' is shorter than b - c.

So b - b' is orthogonal to everything in Im A.  Since being orthogonal to something is a linear condition, it is sufficient to check that b - b' is orthogonal to a spanning set for Im A, for which we can take the columns of A.  As we are using the standard inner product, this means that for each column, say a of A, a<sup>T</sup>(b - b') = 0.  Putting these together, we obtain the relation A<sup>T</sup>(b - b') = 0.  As b' is in the image of A, there is some x' such that b' = A x', whence we see that x' satisfies A<sup>T</sup>b - A<sup>T</sup>A x' = 0, and get the desired formula on rearranging.  This also guarantees the existence of a solution to this equation.

Using the fact that the closest point is the *unique* point b' in Im A such that b - b' is orthogonal to everything in Im A, we can run this argument backwards to see that if x' is a solution of A<sup>T</sup> A x' = A<sup>T</sup> b then Ax' is the closest point to b in Im A.

Where the above answers go wrong is to then talk about the matrix (A<sup>T</sup> A)<sup>-1</sup> A<sup>T</sup>.  The problem with this is that A<sup>T</sup>A **may not be invertible** (take A to be the 2 by 3 zero matrix).  There is a matrix which *when A<sup>T</sup>A is invertible* is (A<sup>T</sup>A)<sup>-1</sup>A<sup>T</sup> and this is called the pseudo-inverse.  Essentially, A<sup>T</sup> misses the kernel of A<sup>T</sup>A meaning that the *composition* is always well-defined but it might not be decomposable as the  notation suggests.

This notation may be standard, of that I don't know, but if it is then it is bad notation because it suggests a property that may not hold.  At the least, it should always carry a rider to make clear that the notation is merely suggestive and not to be taken literally.

Comment: +1 Good catch. I wasn't paying attention. I've modified my answer to explain how to reduce to the case where A<sup>T</sup>A is invertible.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** [Andrew is absolutely correct](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83#126) that using $\left(A^\mathsf TA\right)^{-1}$ is *at best* sloppy (in my case just a flat-out error) because $A^\mathsf TA$ may not be invertible. If $A^\mathsf TA$ is not invertible, it is because there is a linear dependence among the columns of $A$. In this case, you can remove some of the columns without changing the image until they are linearly independent. The explanation I provide below works once you've removed these "extra" columns.

Anon's and las3rjock's answers are correct: the $x^\prime$ you're looking for is $\left(A^\mathsf TA\right)^{-1}A^\mathsf Tb$. But I wanted to add a neat explanation I've heard for **why** this produces the correct answer.

The image of $A$, vectors of the form $Ax$, are all linear combination of the columns of $A$ (the entries of $x$ being the coefficients in the linear combination). So if no solution to the equation $Ax=b$ exists, finding the "best approximate solution" amounts to asking for is the *projection of* $b$ *onto the image of* $A$.

> **Claim:** The operator $A\left(A^\mathsf TA\right)^{-1}A^\mathsf T$
> is the orthogonal projection onto the
> image of A.
>
> Proof:
>
> 1. This operator is equal to
>    its square, so it is a projection:
>    $$
>    A\left(A^\mathsf TA\right)^{-1}A^\mathsf T A\left(A^\mathsf TA\right)^{-1}A^\mathsf T =A\left(A^\mathsf TA\right)^{-1}A^\mathsf T.
>    $$
> 2. For any vector $Ax$ in the image of $A$, we have
>    $$
>    \left(A\left(A^\mathsf TA\right)^{-1}A^\mathsf T\right)Ax=Ax,
>    $$
>    so the image of this projection is equal to the image of $A$.
> 3. The projection is orthogonal. Let me denote inner product by $\langle\cdot , \cdot \rangle$. Suppose $y$ is a vector orthogonal to $Ax$ for all $x$, so $\langle y, Ax\rangle =0$ for all $x$, then we need to show that
>    $$
>    A\left(A^\mathsf TA\right)^{-1}A^\mathsf T y=0.
>    $$
>    For any vector $z$, we have (by the
>    defining property of transpose)
>    $$
>    \langle A\left(A^\mathsf TA\right)^{-1}A^\mathsf T y, z\rangle =\langle y , A\left(B^\mathsf T z\right)\rangle =0
>    $$
>    where $B=\left(A^\mathsf TA\right)^{-1}A^\mathsf T$. Since
>    $A\left(A^\mathsf TA\right)^{-1}A^\mathsf T y $ dots to zero with every z, it must be zero.

So if $b$ is not in the image of $A$, the closest vector that **is** in the image of $A$ is $b^\prime = A\left(A^\mathsf TA\right)^{-1}A^\mathsf T b$, which is clearly $A$ applied to $x^\prime =\left(A^\mathsf TA\right)^{-1}A^\mathsf T b$.

Comment: Down-voted due to presence of (A<sup>T</sup>A)<sup>-1</sup>.

Answer (score 5):

Andrew has a correct answer in the [pseudoinverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) $A^+$, which is characterized by the property that $x = A^+b$ is the shortest vector that solves $A^TAx = A^Tb$ (equivalently, $x$ has zero nullspace(A) component).  Computationally, it is typically found using a singular value decomposition: if

$\displaystyle A = U \Sigma V^T = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} U_{col} & U_{null} \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{cc} \Sigma_{pos} & 0 \\\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right] \left[ \begin{array}{cc} V_{row} & V_{null} \end{array} \right]^T,$

then the pseudoinverse is $A^+ = V_{row} \Sigma_{pos}^{-1} U_{col}^T$.

I'd like to mention that the pseudoinverse is both rather computationally expensive and unstable in the presence of noise.  In particular, if $b$ is given by taking real-world data with limited accuracy, and $A$ is ill-conditioned (e.g., singular), the output of least-squares can vary wildly with the error.  One common approach to rectify this is [Tikhonov regularization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tikhonov_regularization), which typically means minimizing $\Vert Ax - b \Vert^2 + \alpha \Vert x \Vert^2$ for some small $\alpha$.  This generically yields a nonsingular optimization problem, which can be computed quickly by Gaussian elimination, and as $\alpha$ approaches zero, the solution approaches the pseudoinverse solution.  It will not in general yield an exact solution, but there are error-minimizing heuristics (e.g., using the Discrepancy Principle) for choosing $\alpha$ based on knowledge about the size the noise.

Reference: Strang, *Computational Science and Engineering*

Answer (score 3):

As Anon mentions, [linear least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares) is the standard method for solving this problem.  It involves solving the system of linear equations
$$
A^\mathsf TA x = A^\mathsf T b
$$
which are known as the *normal equations*.  If the system is small enough to solve by hand, one can apply Gaussian elimination or calculate the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse $\left(A^\mathsf TA\right)^{-1}A^\mathsf T $ (assuming $A^\mathsf TA$ is invertible), but the standard computer algorithms for solving linear least squares problems use either Cholesky factorization, QR factorization, or singular value decomposition.

Comment: Down-voted due to presence of (A<sup>T</sup>A)<sup>-1</sup>

Comment: I mentioned the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse because I was describing the situation (small m,n) where it should be fairly easy to determine whether or not (A^T A) is invertible.  I agree that the notation is sloppy, but it's fairly common in science and engineering literature (which tends to be sloppy about assumptions and notation).

Answer (score 2):

Multiply by $A^\mathsf T$ (transpose) on both sides and solve using Gauss-Jordan elimination. This gives least squares solution.

Answer (score 2):

Worth a very minor clarification: in the case when $ A^\mbox{T} A$ is not invertible, there is still a single point $y$ in the image (column space) of $A$ that is closest to $b.$ In the annoying extreme that $A$ is the matrix with all entries 0 we will be stuck with $y = 0.$ It is just that when  $ A^\mbox{T} A$ is not invertible  we can no longer guarantee a single ``best''  $ x = \hat{x},$ that is there will be an infinite collection of $x$ satisfying $ A x = y$ with $y$ as above.  Again, when  $A$ is the matrix with all entries 0 then all possible values of $x$ give a "right" answer.

You might enjoy  pages 7-11 and 42-49 in "Kalman Filtering: Theory and Practice" by Mohinder S. Grewal and Angus P. Andrews. The system under consideration is called observable if there is a unique "best answer" $\hat{x},$ which is exactly what happens here when $ A^\mbox{T} A$ is invertible